# Algebraic manipulation solving for $x+y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

There are real solutions $x,y$ to

$x^3+2016x+1=0$

$y^3+2016x-1=0$.

Find $x+y$.

My thinking: adding them we get

$x^3+y^3+2016(x+y)=0$

$(x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2)+2016(x+y)=0$

$(x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2+2016)=0$

Then, either

$x+y=0$

or,

$x^2-xy+y^2+2016=0$.

I’m not sure how to proceed with the second equation and the first seems a little odd.

Comment: Should your second equation be 2016y and not x?

Comment: If $x_1$ is the only one real solution of $x^3+2016x+1=0$, then $y_1:=-x_1$ is the only one real solution of $y^3+2016\color{red}y+1=0$. You need the information of "being real" to eliminate other values for $x+y$. (And thus not involving the parenthesis in the OP...)

Comment: Why does the first seem odd?

Comment: @DanFulea you also need to show that x and y don't have opposite imaginary parts to show there are no other real solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Note that

$$x^2-xy+y^2+2016= \left( x-\frac{1}{2}y \right)^2 +\frac{3}{4}y^2 + 2016>0$$

So, the second equation

$$x^2-xy+y^2+2016=0$$

has no real solutions. Thus, $x+y=0$ is the only solution.

Comment: But what if x+y is real but x-y/2 is imaginary. That would potentially give real solutions for x+y

Comment: The post already states that x and y are real at the start. So, x - y/2 would not be imaginary.

Comment: Actually it only says that real solutions exist, not that x and y have to be real, but I can see why this would cause confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Given:
$$x^3+2016x+1=0 \tag1$$

$$y^3+2016x-1=0 \tag2$$.

When you solve (1) for $x$:

You get a repeated root at $x=-0.000496032$.

When you solve equation (2) for $y$, you get $y=0.000496032$

We can use the values obtained to  calculate $x+y=0$

So the solutions are:
$y=0.000496032$, $x=-0.000496032$ or $x=0.000496032$, $y=-0.000496032$

Another approach is adding equations (1) and (2) to get:

$$x^3-y^3=(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2)=0 \tag3$$

The expression $(x^2+xy+y^2)$ can't be zero for real values of x. This suggests that $x=y$.

Substituting the value of $x$ in Equation (2) we get:
$$y^3+2016(-y)-1=0$$

which has a real solution $y=0.000496032$.

So the solutions are (for which $x+y=0$ and both $x,y$ are real):

$y=0.000496032$, $x=-0.000496032$ or $x=0.000496032$, $y=-0.000496032$

Note: I use the equal sign loosely here the accurate values may not be fully precise.